# (How) Can I overrule read-only descriptors of build-in types?

Tags: python, hook, decorator

Is it possible to access an attribute that is set to not be accessed? E.g. to set a new `get` method for a `dict`?

I am trying to get into a large and sometimes confusing code base. To get a hang of things I was trying to decorate some methods to print a log every time they are called. Python decorators (that do not actually decorate, I know) work fine to wrap our own methods but when I tried to (this time truely) decorate `dict.get` there was a problem. I expected `my_dict.get = my_wrapper(my_dict.get)` to work fine but got an `AttributeError` with the message `'dict' object attribute 'get' is read-only`.

According to my research that means that dict uses a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to handle the assignment (i.e. raise an Exception insetad of handling it). I tried to hook into the descriptor itself or the `__dict__` of `dict` but nothing helped and I couldn't find any source that was detailed enought to be helpful either.

Subclassing is a workaround and propably the way to go here but I allways thought that one could access and hook into anything in Python and that preventing the users from doing something is just meant to make them think twice before doing something more acurate or do the thing anyways, this time more explicid. Is that a misconception or did I miss something that makes `dict_instance.get = my_wrapper(dict_instance.get)` work?

Python can hook into things and does not need a new class just to change a single attribute of a single instance, possibly breaking code that relies on the exact type of that instance, right?

Comment: You'll need to subclass, yes. `dict` is written in C and doesn't support assigning attributes or methods. Many of the built-in types are this way.

Comment: I know that they are (and have to be) written in C but why don't they support assignments? This has to be a design decision, but I don't get why Python would breakes the concept and wouldn't allow use cases like this. Fortunally the fact that I changed the type of the object didn't break any code (yet) but in other cases it might. Sure, you don't usually check for `type(something)`, but it is well possible that e.g. some library depends on it, effectively breaking the code beyond fixing. Is it possible to fine tune the subclassing approach to make `type(something)` still return `dict`?

Comment: Well, you could redefine `type()` to do whatever you want, but I would wait until you actually encounter a problem with subclasses before doing that.

Comment: This is heading the wrong direction. I just wanted to decorate a method -- now we are talking about messing with type itself. For function decoration it is possible to make the helper funtion mimic the decorated function in introspection, doesn't that work for classes too? Maybe if we can't decorate the function, we can decorate the class in a way that still allows any other code to work the same way it used to even if it relies on the type of things. Anyway you should post an answer. It's not like the question is unclear but I can't accept comments.